# Disabling Java's unlimited strength policy file

Tags: java, security, encryption, policyfiles

I have an app that I'm deploying to an environment where I can't count on an unlimited-strength policy file, and I'm having trouble testing that I'm selecting a legal encryption algorithm, key size, etc. for that environment. Is there a way I can temporarily revert to the default configuration, some file I can move or blow away? Better yet, is there a way to test this programmatically?

Comment: [security.se](http://security.stackexchange.com) might be a better forum for this.

Comment: There's a lot more questions on SO about Java policy files than there are on security.

Comment: ah, I didn't see [tag:policyfiles].  Fair enough.

Comment: I didn't realize there was a tag till after seeing your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restore the original versions of the following files as distributed with the JRE:

```
lib/security/local_policy.jar
lib/security/US_export_policy.jar
```

or if either of those isn't provided with the default JRE at all, remove it for your testing.